# Подтверждение перехода на другую страницу

Tags: javascript, html

Почему-то не переходит на другую страницу при нажатии "ок"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Java Script4</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" id="form">Возраст:
            <input type="text" name="username">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="ok" value="Ок" />
            <input type="submit" name="cancel" value=" не Ок" />
        </form>
        <script>
            form.elements.cancel.addEventListener("click", function () {
                var a = confirm("Вы уверены?");
                if (a == true) {
                    window.location.href = "http://home.netscape.com/";
                } else {
                    alert("Вы отменили сохранение");
                }
            })

             form.elements.username.addEventListener("keypress", function () {

                if ((event.keyCode < 48) || (event.keyCode > 57)) {
                    alert("Не пытайтесь обмануть, вводите числа!");
                }
            })
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @alexkate, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (confirm("Вы уверены?")){
    window.location.href="http://home.netscape.com/"; 
} else { 
    alert("Вы отменили сохранение");
}
```

Comment: без return false или event.preventDefault() - submit все равно будет происходить

Comment: спасибо, все вроде справедливо, но при нажатии 'ок' реакции.

Comment: надо не window.location.href="http://home.netscape.com/"; а document.location.href="http://home.netscape.com/";
Довольно распространенная ошибка

Comment: Можно сократить код тернарным оператором:

     confirm("Вы уверены?")?window.location.href="http://home.netscape.com/":alert("Вы отменили сохранение");

Comment: @Barton, как раз наоборот, `document.location` — распространенная во времена home.netscape.com ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

1. `if (a===true)`
2. при else  нужно делать `return false;`

Comment: а вообще логика нарушена. Кликая на отмену - задается вопрос "вы уверены". И если да - то по идее должно быть отмена, а не  window.location.href = "http://home.netscape.com/";